# Retagging Questions marked as "Beginner"

Tags: discussion, tagging, retagging

Someone mentioned that the beginner tag is not one that is really encouraged, and this meta topic [Should we be adding tags like [beginner] to questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59077/should-we-be-adding-tags-like-beginner-to-questions) has some information on using tags like beginner or expert.

Should we be using those here?  Should the tag be removed?

There are [6 Questions Tagged Beginner on this Site](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner).

Comment: Not to mention questions also tagged with "best practice".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should almost certainly be removed, as it is a meta tag.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

The two basic tests for a meta tag are

1. Could a question have *only* this tag?
2. Does this tag mean different things to different people in your field?

I think this tag fails both criteria.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the questions tagged "beginner" have already been retagged.  That's great.  I think the ["best practices" questions](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practices) also need to have that tag removed.  Those questions are all over the map, and are better described by tags related to the content of the questions ("documentation", "tools", whatever).